# I can not make DB dump using mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make DB dump using mysqldump like below,

```
# mysql -u root -p 
after i login, i did command like below,
#mysql>  mysqldump -u root -p --no-data Dbname > /var/lib/myfolder/MyDB.sql
```

if i enter then it gives like below,

```
mysql> mysqldump -u root -p --no-data Dbname > /var/lib/myfolder/MyDB.sql
    ->
    ->
    ->
    ->
    ->
```

I can not do anything than CTR+C. where am i doing silly mistakes?

Answer (score 2):

Issue the command at shell level, not from within mysql, i.e. instead of

```
# mysql -u root...
```

type

```
# mysqldump -u root -p --no-data Dbname > /var/lib/myfolder/MyDB.sql
```

Comment: @mmmms See my edit. Sorry for being short, I'm on my mobile.

Comment: @MMMMS You're welcome. I'd appreciate if you'd _accept_ the answer then. btw: in your attempt mysql was waiting for the final `;` to end the statement. If you'd given it mysql would have complained about syntax errors (which would not have helped, though).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `;` at the end of the command. Try it like so:

```
mysql> mysqldump -u root -p --no-data Dbname > /var/lib/myfolder/MyDB.sql;
```